# Complex member fields

Tags: members, member-details

RE: http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/cp/members/custom_member_fields_edit.html

Is it possible to have a group of fields to represent a single entry (of a possible many) in member fields? For example, say the member is to list his/her professional services, it may look like this:

```
1 hour(s), Web Development, $100
1 hour(s), Web Design, $125
1 hour(s), Web Content Development, $75
```

Each entry contains 3 fields. Is this natively possible? Do I need some sort of addon? Or is this not supported at all?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do. But given the fact that the native Member module is not good for much of anything, I always recommend not using it. Using an add-on that stores profiles in channel entries allows you to use any fieldtype you want and get the level of flexibility you need. I am sure there is a fieldtype (FT) available to what you need, and you already used the word "entries" which tells me one of these add-ons would be exactly what you need.

All of these are solid solutions

- http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/safecracker-registration (My add-on)
- http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/zoo-visitor
- http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/profileedit

Comment: What is a "FT"? I just need to support entries that require multiple fields per entry for each member. So, in my example, say an IT professional is listing down his/her rates for various services.

Comment: FT == fieldtype. Sorry about that, I edited the posted. But yes, no matter the case, store all the data in the channel entries you can. It will make your life easier in the long run.

Comment: I guess what I need are "line entries". Is that possible?

Comment: Justin's list of recommended modules that will allow members to be stored as 'Channel Entries' is what you are looking for. Once in place, you could then use a Matrix field to create a list of services for your members.

Comment: Matrix fields allow for line item entries?

Comment: Pixel and Tonic's Matrix, http://pixelandtonic.com/matrix, allows you to basically build rows and columns of information, where the number of returns does not have to be pre-defined. Basically this means one consultant can offer 5 services and fees, while another only offers 1. You define the heading specifications— service, amount, length of time— and they keep adding rows until they are done.

Comment: Matrix is pretty much the one add-on every EE developer uses across the board without hesitation. It's top-notch.

Comment: Thanks. I shall purchase Matrix, then. Now, I just need to explore the 3 linked addons a bit more to see if they'll let me do what I want. I want somewhat complex member profiles.